# creating producer and consumer application in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to write a producer and consumer code in python using pika for rabbitmq. However for my specific case, I need to run producer on a different host and consumer on other.

I have already written a producer code as:

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('ip add of another host', 5672, '/', credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='test', body='hello all!')
print (" [x] sent 'Hello all!")

connection.close()
```

The above producer code is running without any error. I also created a new user and gave administrator credentials to it on rabbitmq-server. However when I run the consumer code on another host running rabbitmq-server, I do not see any output:

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', 5672, '/', credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   print(" [x] Recieved %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(
      queue='test', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print (' [x] waiting for messages. To exit press ctrl+c')

channel.start_consume()
```

So, here i had two hosts on the same network which had rabbitmq installed. However one has 3.7.10 and other had 3.7.16 version of rabbitmq.

The producer is able to send the text without error, but the consumer on another host is not receiving any text.

I do not get any problem when both run on same machine, as i just replace connection settings with localhost. Since user guest is only allowed to connect on localhost by default, i created a new user on consumer host running rabbitmq-server.

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer and producer applications must connect to the **same** RabbitMQ server. If you have two instances of RabbitMQ running they are independent. Messages do not move from one instance of RabbitMQ to another unless you configure Shovel or Federation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be passing the `parameters` to the `BlockingConnection` instance.

```
import pika

rmq_server = "ip_address_of_rmq_server"
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(rmq_server, 5672, '/', credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
```

Also, your consumer is attaching to the `localhost` hostname.  Make sure this actually resolves and that your RabbitMQ service is listening on the localhost address (127.0.0.1)  It may not be bound to that address.  I believe that RMQ will bind to all interfaces (and thus all addresses) by default but I'm not sure.